# Hide the "addtocart'" button in Virtuemart for not logged in users

Tags: php, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am trying to customise a Virtuemart Template in order to hide the ADD TO CART button only for users who are not logged in or unregistered. 
I am using Virtuemart 2.0.x and Joomla 2.5.x

I have added this code in the "default_addtocart.php" file after line 122: (/templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/com_virtuemart/productdetails/)

after this code:

```
            <span class="addtocart-button">
            <?php echo shopFunctionsF::getAddToCartButton ($this->product->orderable); ?>
```

I have added this code:

```
        <?php if ($_SESSION['auth']['user_id'] = 1) { ?>
            <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            .addtocart-area, .addtocart-bar, .quantity-box, .addtocart-button { display:none;}
            </style>
```

This makes the "addtocart" button to be hidden, but for all usergroups, regardless if a user is logged in or not.

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: It should be `== 1`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
        <?php 
                $user = JFactory::getUser();
                if($user->id <= 0):
           ?>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .addtocart-area, .addtocart-bar, .quantity-box, .addtocart-button { display:none;}
        </style>

       <?php endif; ?>
```